# Recoger información de formulario ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-core

Muy buenas, soy nuevo utilizando ASP.NET y tengo problemas para recoger los datos:

En una vista muestro varios elementos en una tabla y en la última columna hay un cuadro de texto para rellenar por el usuario el problema es que no sé como recoger en el controlador del Post todas las cadenas de texto de cada uno de los formularios. Agradecería que alguien me ayudase con esto. Gracias de antemano.

```
@if (Model.Habitaciones.Count == 0)
            {
                <tr><td colsapn="3">No hay habitaciones disponibles</td></tr>
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (Habitacion hab in Model.Habitaciones)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => hab.NHabitacion)
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => hab.Tipo.NombreTipo)
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => hab.Precio)
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="Coments" value="Observacion" class="w-50"/>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una de las opciones:
Primero en tu controlador que parametros queres recibir o que parametros queres enviar desde la vista y en tu vista debes colocar tus etiquetas que queres enviar dentro de un `form action`.
Segundo en el `ActionResult` de tu controlador, dejar establecidos cada parametro con el `name` de tu `input`.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
{
    <input type="text" name="comments" />
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
}
```

y en tu controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string comments)// esta variable lleva el mismo nombre que el name de tu input.
{ 
  return View();
}
```

Esta es una breve descripcion de enviar datos desde vista a controlador, y hay opciones manejando modelos.

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias